# How do i find the bundle identifier or app bundle on iOS for custom UIActivity

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'd like to know where user would share my app, so i create some of code on completionWithItemsHandler, but UIKit only provide some of apps like fb, twitter, then how about Telegram and Line ? Where should i find them ? I just found for whatsapp

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak s] activityType, completed, _, error in
                    guard let ss = s,
                        let activityType = activityType,
                        completed else { return }

                    if error != nil {
                        return
                    }

                    var action: String = ""
                    switch activityType {
                    case .postToFacebook:
                        action = "facebook"
                    case .postToTwitter:
                        action = "twitter"
                    case .message:
                        action = "message"
                    case .mail:
                        action = "mail"
                    case UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"):
                        action = "whatsapp"
                    default:
                        action = "others"
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telegram: `ph.telegra.Telegraph`
Line: `jp.naver.line`

Please refer to link below:
[finding-the-app-bundle-id](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/finding-the-app-bundle-id/)

For the Whatsapp, it was `net.whatsapp.WhatsApp`
I don't know what is`extension` is for

Comment: I'd like to know what is activity that user choose, because this block is used as code to handle sharing url to another app